# Castle ActiveRecord and AfterLoad event

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, castle

`Castle ActiveRecord` has `BeforeLoad` event but I need `AfterLoad` event too. I know it's possible to use NHibernate's PostLoad event. But how can I do this?

Comment: I noticed you had posted a sample solution on your website: http://blog.afsharm.com/2010/09/using-nhibernate-event-model-in-castle.html - thanks!

Comment: @Lessan, glad if helped anyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord's "events" are based on [NHibernate interceptors](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-interceptors) (`IInterceptor`), not [NHibernate events](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events). `IInterceptor` doesn't have any `PostLoad`, so there's no overridable `AfterLoad` method in ActiveRecord.

[Here are the docs on how to hook up event listeners in ActiveRecord](http://using.castleproject.org/display/AR/NHEventListenerSpecs#NHEventListenerSpecs-Configuration).

Comment: So how can I do some code just after loading an entity in AR?

Comment: @afsharm: hook up a IPostLoadEventListener

Comment: IPostLoadEventListener is in event model. Am I right? if yes, how can I hook it up while you say AR is based on NHibernate interceptors not event model?

Comment: @afsharm: see the link I posted to the docs on how to hook up event listeners in ActiveRecord.